# XSLT: how do I iterate nodes and only output once if condition is met, but multiple conditions needed

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, recursion

I'm new to XSL and am struggling to figure out how to do what I need to do. I have a dataset of orders and am transforming it into a format I can use to import the orders into a fulfillment system. I'm using a for-each to iterate through the nodes and output the data. Simple enough to that point.

Now a new requirement is that I need to check for values in the subnodes of item. If any of those values are defined, I need to add an additional line to my output. The tricky part is that this additional line is decided at the item level, but should only be in my output once even if the value is found in multiple subnodes. That's where I'm at a loss without being able to assign variable values or breaking a for-each. I'm sure recursion of some sort is the answer but I can't figure out how that would work without reiterating all the item nodes for each property I'm trying to find. I'm also restricted to XSLT 1.0 as this must be done through a third-party application that doesn't support 2.0.

Here's a sample of my dataset

```
<orders>
<order>
    <id>1</id>
    <items>
        <item>
            <sku>12345</sku>
            <price>5.00</sku>
        </item>
        <item>
            <sku>23456</sku>
            <price>4.00</sku>
            <options>
                <option1>item_upgrade</option1>
            </option>
        </item>
        <item>
            <item>
            <sku>34567</sku>
            <price>3.00</sku>
            <options>
                <option2>finish_upgrade</option2>
            </option>
        </item>
        <item>
            <sku>45678</sku>
            <price>2.00</sku>
            <options>
                <option1>item_upgrade</option1>
                <option2>finish_upgrade</option2>
            </option>
        </item>
   </items>
</order>
<order>
    <id>2</id>
    <items>
        <item>
            <sku>12345</sku>
            <price>5.00</sku>
        </item>
        <item>
            <sku>23456</sku>
            <price>4.00</sku>
        </item>
        <item>
            <item>
            <sku>34567</sku>
            <price>3.00</sku>
        </item>
   </items>
</order>
<order>
....
</order>
</orders>
```

What I'd like that to look like in the end would be

```
   1 12345 5.00
   1 23456 4.00
   1 99999 0.00
   1 34567 3.00
   1 88888 0.00
   1 45678 2.00
   2 12345 5.00
   2 23456 4.00
   2 34567 3.00
   ...
```

99999 and 88888 do not exist in the source data anywhere, but are static values in the fulfillment system to represent item_upgrade and finish_upgrade respectively. If item_upgrade is defined on any item within an order, then a line for 99999 should be added to the output. Same for finish_upgrade, which would need a line added for 88888 to the output. The sort order of these static entries, such as 99999, does not matter, as long as it remains sorted by the order/id. The same options can existed on multiple item nodes, and do not necessarily exist on any.

What I'm using this for is to add surcharge fees to the orders in the import file I'm creating. These fees are at the order level and should be a single line if that particular option was selected on any item contained in the order. The fees do not exist within the source data and cannot be added. Luckily they are static values so I only need to figure out when to add them.

The current approach with the for-each without accounting for these fees looks like

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="orders/order/items/item">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../id" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sku" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="price" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If I wanted to add in this static fee for any occurence, allowing it multiple times within a single order, I'd add in something like

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="orders/order/items/item">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../id" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sku" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="price" />
        <xsl:if test="options/option1='item_upgrade'">
           <xsl:value-of select="../../id" />
           <xsl:text> 99999 0.00</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="options/option2='finish_upgrade'">
           <xsl:value-of select="../../id" />
           <xsl:text> 88888 0.00</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This is where I'm stuck. Adding this value needs done once per order, but whether to add it needs to be decided at the item level. I'm hoping this is something easy for someone who understands this better, but with any approach I've taken so far I come back to having the additional static lines added for every occurrence, rather than once for the whole order even if the same option is defined on multiple items within a single order. Can anyone steer me towards an approach that would work for this? Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not exactly easy. Please state if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Also explain where do the values `color` and `shape` come from. -- Note also that your example is confusing, because there is no `45678` in the input.

Comment: It's XSLT 1.0. I changed the example to hopefully make the color and shape values more clear. Those values do not exist in the source and I'm adding them to the output, and adding them is triggered by finding the options defined in the source.

The missing 45678 was my mistake on a copy/paste, and has been fixed as well.

Comment: I am still confused by this: your input uses `<option1>` for `item_upgrade`, and `<option2>` for `finish_upgrade`, Is there any significance to these names, or should the stylesheet ignore them and consider only the string values?

Comment: I have to check the text value of the nodes because they can have something in them besides item_upgrade in <option1> or finish_upgrade in <option2>, but I only want to add these extra lines if what is defined in those matches certain values. They can have other text, but aren't necessarily defined for all <item> nodes because the <item> can have different attribute sets and some do not include these options at all

Comment: I am afraid it's not getting any clearer. Anyway, I have posted an answer that should serve as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this is a *grouping* problem and since you're using XSLT 1.0 it's best handled using the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="opt" match="options/*" use="concat(ancestor::order/id, '|', .)" />

<xsl:template match="/orders">
    <xsl:for-each select="order">
        <xsl:variable name="order-id" select="id" />
        <!-- items -->
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <xsl:value-of select="$order-id" />
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="sku" />
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="price" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- options -->
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item/options/*[count(. | key('opt', concat($order-id, '|', .))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="$order-id" />
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:text>&#9;0.00&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following well-formed (!) input example:

**XML**

```
<orders>
   <order>
      <id>1</id>
      <items>
         <item>
            <sku>12345</sku>
            <price>5.00</price>
         </item>
         <item>
            <sku>23456</sku>
            <price>4.00</price>
            <options>
               <option1>red</option1>
            </options>
         </item>
         <item>
            <sku>34567</sku>
            <price>3.00</price>
            <options>
               <option2>circle</option2>
            </options>
         </item>
         <item>
            <sku>45678</sku>
            <price>4.00</price>
            <options>
               <option1>red</option1>
            </options>
         </item>
      </items>
   </order>
   <order>
      <id>2</id>
      <items>
         <item>
            <sku>12345</sku>
            <price>5.00</price>
         </item>
         <item>
            <sku>23456</sku>
            <price>4.00</price>
         </item>
         <item>
            <sku>34567</sku>
            <price>3.00</price>
         </item>
      </items>
   </order>
</orders>
```

the result will be:

```
1   12345   5.00
1   23456   4.00
1   34567   3.00
1   45678   4.00
1   red     0.00
1   circle  0.00
2   12345   5.00
2   23456   4.00
2   34567   3.00
```

Comment: Thank you. That's getting me closer to what I need. Can it be manipulated to be more generic and check for any value in a key? For example, if option1 is defined for any item on an order regardless of its actual value? Say 23456 has `<option1>blue</option1>`, 45678 has `<option1>red</option1>`, and 34567 has `<option1></option1>` so it's there on those 3 items but one has it blank and for the other two I want to group them even though the text value is different.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, if you use `name()` instead of `.`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I still have a little tweaking to do, but this grouping looks like it is going to let me do what I need to do.